# Rails prevent db:migrate from running subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I have a structure like so for my migrations

- db/migrate

  - xx_create_sites.rb
  - site

    - xx_create_users.rb

The `site` directory includes migrations that only need to run on a separate DB. I have a working rake task for those

```
desc "Migrate the database through scripts in db/migrate/site."
namespace :db do

  task :sites => :environment do
    @sites = Site.all()
    for site in @sites do
        conn_config = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
        conn_config[:database] = site.id
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection conn_config
        ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate/site/").migrate
    end
  end
end
```

However, if I run `bin/rails db:migrate` for the default database, it also runs the site directory migrations into the overall database... How can I prevent this folder from being migrated?

Comment: This runs migrations in subfolders. I need to ignore a subfolder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it globs every file in `db/migrate` so pick a different folder outside of that dir

Comment: @Anthony that worked, thanks. Care to form an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails expects migrations to be in `db/migrate` and it globs everything in that directory when running them (see: [the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration)).

If you want to keep some migrations localized for some reason, you need to move them out of `db/migrate` and have your custom rake task point to that dir.